# Open Detail information of cell data in other tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am taking data from server and displaying that data in tableview.Now I want to display detail data on the other table view after clicking cell of tableview.for example if i click on fist cell then detail data of that cell show on other tableview.Any tutorial or sample code.

Comment: I have saved all data in array.If I click on cell1 then array1 data should upload dynamically in next view.

Answer (score 0):

use this method.Suppose Secondtable is your other tableView class which you want to open on clicking cell.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

SecondTable *leaderBoard =[[SecondTable alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondTable" bundle:nil];
leaderBoard.passedGlobalMailID = passedGlobalInMenu;
leaderBoard.nameOfPlayer = nameOfPlayerInMenu;
leaderBoard.no_of_wins = no_of_winsInMenu;
leaderBoard.no_of_coins = no_of_coinsInMenu;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:leaderBoard animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Actually i am using dynamic data.cell value and data value are dynamic.

Comment: store that data into array and pass array element into second table